# How to enable WebRTC AEC in PJSIP 2.8 for iOS?

Tags: ios, webrtc, echo, pjsip

WebRTC AEC is already built in pjsip 2.8, I'm using these settings

```
   app_config.media_cfg.ec_options = PJMEDIA_ECHO_WEBRTC.rawValue
   app_config.media_cfg.ec_tail_len = 30
```

then init

```
    status = pjsua_init(&(app_config.cfg), &(app_config.log_cfg), &(app_config.media_cfg))
```

but it won't start, there should be 'WebRTC AEC mobile successfully created with options' at logs at least.

config_site.h includes

```
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_WEBRTC_AEC 1
```

**UPDATE:** I found the solution, PJMEDIA_ECHO_USE_SW_ECHO flag should be used to force SW ED instead of device EC.

Comment: You should provide the solution as an answer to your own question, then accept the answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PJMEDIA_ECHO_USE_SW_ECHO` flag should be used to force SW ED instead of device EC.